# Bootstrap 3 Grid system, make first column fullwidth if second is missing

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose in below code there is `$someThingIsTrue` is false.
Is there any class or property for container row to **set first column width 100% if second column is missing**?

*Please be aware I'm looking for only Bootstrap solution (because I understand too that I can write same if statement and set col-lg-12 for first column if needed)*

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">Some content here</div>

        <?php if($someThingIsTrue): ?>
           <div class="col-lg-6">Other content here</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: In Bootstrap 3 you can't but in 4 u can

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want to do it in PHP:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-<?= ($someThingIsTrue ? '6' : '12') ?>">Some content here</div>
    <?php if ($someThingIsTrue): ?>
    <div class="col-lg-6">Other content here</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Or if you are using [bootstrap 4 you can use flexbox](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/), your need to put `width:100%` on each item.

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="p-2">Other content here</div>
  <?php if ($someThingIsTrue): ?>
  <div class="p-2">Some Other content here</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

**Here is an example (view snippet):**

```css
.box {
  width:100%;
}

.box-blue {
  background:blue;
}

.box-red {
  background:red;
}

.box-green {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="p-2 box box-red">Other content here</div>
  <div class="p-2 box box-blue">Some Other content here</div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="p-2 box box-green">Some Other content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because its not a bootsrap solution as I asked in my question, can I guess that there is no bootsrap solution for this situation?

Comment: I upwote it because its realy useful, but I looking for solution for bootrsrap 3, I will edit my question now

Answer (score 0):

You can set class in php variable `$class` as follows:

```
<div class="row">
        <?php
            if($someThingIsTrue)
               $class= 'col-lg-6';
            else
               $class = 'col-lg-12';
           endif; 
        ?>
        <div class="<?php echo $class;">Some content here</div>

        <?php if($someThingIsTrue): ?>
           <div class="col-gl-6">Other content here</div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read again my question and edit your answer if you know solution

Comment: I think there is no direct bootstrap solution. Another way you can handle using javascript/jQuery. You can check `whether second column exists` using jQuery and accordingly change class of first column using jQuery. Other option might be using css.